# Slow Samsung 830 SSD!

Tags: performance, ssd, samsung

I did a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04.1, ext4 with discard option & swappiness set to 0, mounting temp directory in RAM, (8GB.)

I found performance was not stellar, in fact, marginally better than traditional spinning storage media.  This drive has had good reviews, yet I have seen Windows users complaining of slow performance online.  It was anything other than zippy, with application loads being plain dog slow & not instant like I expected.  I RMAd it eventually (GSmartControl would never complete long test.)

Slow performance on Windows = slow performance on Linux?  Would I fare better with another brand?

I now have a 840 & it is not legendary, but faster than HDD.

Comment: I have the same drive and it is fast. Do you have the right connectors? I mean are you connecting it to a slow sata interface?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201106-8081/ This is my hardware & I am using 64-bit Xubuntu. I mean it was total pants for me.

Comment: Ok for the hardware. Do you have sata 3 or sata 6?

Comment: I'm not sure?!?

Comment: Some speed measures from the 830 would have been interesting, like `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdX`. I have multiple 830's both on Win and Linux and they are as fast as they should be. Maybe you had a faulty one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you answered your own question there, the drivers used to control sata disks are normally pretty generic - unless you are using special hardware - and do the same on both Windows and Linux.

If this drive is slow on Windows it will probably also be slow on any Linux system. You should replace it or check if Samsung has a firmware upgrade that would eventually solve this issue.

Remember when I first changed from a spinning plate drive to a SSD, there is no comparison on boot and applications access. This is a disk model problem and should be handled with Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

I just succeeded in updating the firmware of my Samsung 840 SSD. I used a libvirt-bin kvm, installing Windows 7 into a 16Gib virtual disk. I plugged in a USB drive, and used the virt-manager to give it to the vm running Windows 7. I installed the Samsung software, and had it make a bootable USB drive. I rebooted the laptop with that USB drive, and it updated the firmware with no problems.

I have asked Samsung to please provide USB bootable images for Linux users who don't have access to Windows 7... Perhaps if they hear it enough times, they'll do it.